# Making sheet wider

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a sheet with the same width of the screen.

I've already tried with `presentationDetents`, but I'm not able to make it work on iPad (iPadOS16).

For example,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("View Sheet") {
            showSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text("HELLO")
        }
    }
}
```

How can I edit sheet's width?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: It's more like a general question, for every sheet. However, I did a little edit.

Comment: Sheets are popovers they look different on iPad that is by design. you can try full screen cover but if that doesn't meet your needs you have to create your own.

Comment: As suggested you can use `fullScreenCover` for the iPad to cover full width but this will cover full height as well.

Comment: Thanks! It fits more or less what I wanted to do, I didn't know about it